# Xcode pods.framework file pointing to wrong derived data directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

`Xcode` cannot find my `Frameworks/Pods.framework` file. I can see it's pointing to wrong directory. 
The file exists in `...Xcode/DerivedData/projectName/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator` but `Xcode` is looking for it in `...Debug-iphoneos` folder.

From where `cocoapods` get the path of derived data folder? I am not able to find any setting that could change the path. Also the project is working properly on another computer. I already tried to remove and add back `cocoapods` to the project in hope the path will get set correctly but it didn't help.

I am using `Xcode 10.1`

Comment: try to clean up your project Cmd+Shift+K, also you can clean up derived data Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> DerivedData, remove folder and rebuild project

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. Xcode is still looking for the file in the same, wrong folder.

Comment: what a framework?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik sorry if the title was a bit misleading: I am talking about pods_project_name.framework file that gets generated when you run pod install.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps:-

1)Project-> General tab-> Embedded binaries-> (-) (Remove) all your framework

2) Project-> General tab-> Embedded binaries-> (+) Select your framework or go to add other->  Select your framework

3) clean and build

Comment: This answer is outdated @ Xcode 12.5.1